# How to break a loop onClick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that does some animation using  `async await()`. **I want to play/pause the animation `onClick`**. I used `useState` to update the variable but the function is not behaving as I want. While the `const print ()` is running and when I click on the button, text updates, but the function doesn't break. In the log, "play" is printed 100 times. I'm guessing  `useState` and `async` is causing something. How can I solve this?

```
const Test= props => {

    const [ButtonText, SetButtonText] = useState("Play");
    const ToggleButtonText = () => {
        if(ButtonText == "Play")          
            SetButtonText("Pause")

        if(ButtonText == "Pause")
            SetButtonText("Play")
    }

    const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

    const print= () => {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)        
        {
            ///
               work
               await delay(1000);
               work
            ///
           console.log(ButtonText);
           
           if(ButtonText == "Pause")
               break ; 

        }
    };
    return (
           <div>
              <div>
                   ///work component///
              </div>
            <button onClick = {() => ToggleButtonText()}> {ButtonText}</button>
           </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please use lowercase for variables. Capitals are for classes and components. Rejecting this convention makes the code unnecessarily hard to understand.

Comment: Related: [How to break out of an async for loop on button press in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720229/how-to-break-out-of-an-async-for-loop-on-button-press-in-react/73720724#73720724)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ButtonText` is declared as `const` - it can't change its value inside a given call of the functional component.

Without more info, I'd use a ref as well as state, so that the loop can see if the ref gets changed:

```
const buttonTextRef = useRef();
// Update the ref to ButtonText every time ButtonText changes:
useEffect(() => {
  buttonTextRef.current = ButtonText;
}, [ButtonText]);
```

```
if (buttonTextRef.current === 'Pause') {
  break;
}
```

Another method would be to put the index being iterated over into state, and instead of looping 100 times, re-render 100 times, eg, something along the lines of:

```
const [printI, setPrintI] = useState(0);
if (printI) {
  // Then we're in the middle of iterating
  // work
  if (printI < 100) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPrintI(printI + 1);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    setPrintI(0);
  }
};
```

and to stop it, call `setPrintI(0)`.

Comment: I'm trying the first method, buttonTextRef, the variable is not updating inside the loop. i have print  `console.log(buttonTextRef.current+ " " +ButtonText ); ` after await to check, each time it prints `play play `. I tried `var` instead of  `const` but still not working.

Comment: Are you sure you used the `useEffect` in the answer? If implemented properly, it will update the ref.

Comment: I think I used it properly. since I'm using `await`I have to declare the function as  `const print= async () =>`  that's all I added extra. In `SetButtonText` function both `ButtonText` and `buttonTextRef` are updating properly.

Comment: Can you edit a live snippet into the question illustraing the problem, or a link to a codesandbox or something? `buttonTextRef.current = ButtonText;` *really really should* update the ref properly every time `ButtonText` updates, it sounds like there's something else going on

Comment: here codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-water-euo1q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh man. Typo on my part. `const buttonTextRef = useRef();`, not `useState`